# Show there are no holes in the Reals?

Tags: real-analysis

$S=\{x\in\mathbb R | x\lt1\}$ How do you show $x$ is arbitrarily close to $1$? I see that it is true but am confused how I would show that $1$ is the least upper bound of $S$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Show that $1$ is indeed larger than every element in your set.  (*Hint, what is the defining trait of elements in your set*).  Suppose that there was some other smaller number $s$ distinct from $1$ that might have acted as a supremum of your set.  What is the average of $s$ and $1$?  Is that larger than or smaller than $s$?  Larger than or smaller than $1$? Is that in your set?  Was $s$ then a valid choice for your supremum?

Comment: $x$ isn't a thing - it is a bound variable. No single value of $S$ is arbitrarily close to $1.$

Answer (score 1):

If I say: "You cannot point out an $x\in S$ which is less than $0.1$ away from $1$!"

You'll reply: "Actually, $x=0.95$ will do."

Then I'll say: "OK, but no way you can point out another $x\in S$ which is less than $0.01$ away from $1$!"

You'll still be able to reply something to this.

And then generalize.

Comment: the obvious generalization being, if you request an $x \in S$ which is less than $\epsilon$ away from $1$ for any $\epsilon>0 \in \mathbb R$, you may verify the real number $1-\epsilon/2$ works and is a member of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Given any $~\delta > 0,~$ (no matter how small), since $~(1 - \delta) < 1,~$ you have that (by definition), $~(1 - \delta)~$ is an element of $~S.$

$~1~$ is clearly **an** upper bound for $~S.$

By the least upper bound axiom, since $~S~$ is bounded above, it must have a least upper bound $~L.$

Thus, if $~L < 1,~$ there would exist a $~\delta > 0,~$ such that $~(1 - L) = 2\delta,~$ which would imply that $~L < (1 - \delta),~$ which implies that $~(1 - \delta)~$ is not an element of $~S,~$ thus contradicting the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is not the point, but since you didn't say what's topology you're working "Show there are no holes in the Reals?", I would ask you about discrete topology and get that all points of $S$ is isolated, this is, there is not a $x$ arbitrary close to $1$.